# How to Parallelize C++ Vector Writes

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

```
std::vector<size_t> vector;
    std::vector<size_t> v_vector;
```

Hello,
Suppose 2 threads are reading from "**vector**" and compute a simple math operation and then save the result in **v_vector**.

Using a global mutex to ensure that the threads are locking and unlocking the **same** mutex how would one parallelize this so that the 2 threads are reading, computing the math operation, and storing the content in **v_vector** faster than a single thread.

Ideas so far, divide vector.size() in half. Have thread 1 iterate from 0 to vector half, and have the 2nd thread iterate from vector half to vector end. (however, there seems to be a write access violation from this, not sure why as the vector writes for both threads are protected by a mutex)

The order in which the threads push values into **v_vector** does not matter.

Any other ideas or if you see any logic issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you should just use the parallel accumulation function in the standard library.

Comment: Hi @user17732522, the total size of **vector** is 2.1million lines of text. The calculation without parallelizing takes 22000ms however I am required to parallelize as a requirement for a university module. The threads should be accessing every element (2.1million) and computing a math operation and then pushing the math operation result onto **v_vector** essentially filling up **v_vector** with 2.1million indices.

Comment: @Mutlithrd A picture paints a thousand words.  Please post some representative code, see [mre].

Comment: Hi @PaulSanders, I have added some code!

Comment: It is still not a [mre] and I don't see the code reproducing the access violation. But if the individual sizes of the strings aren't very large, this will be slower than single-threaded, because you will spent most time waiting for the lock on the vector. Resize `v_vector` first and then access it by index `i` as well, without a mutex.

Comment: @Mutlithrd What code?  I may be getting on in years but I still know it when I see it. ... Oh, OK, scratch that, you rolled it back.

Comment: Also note that there are parallel versions of the standard library algorithms e.g. `v_vector.resize(vector.size()); std::transform(std::execution::par, vector.begin(), vector.end(), v_vector.begin(), std::hash<std::string>{});`. They do take care of the work distribution for simple cases like this. (Although you might want to tweak the details with a manual implementation.)

Answer (score 2):

As long as no thread resizes the vectors you can have many threads reading and writing as you want. The vector won't care.

All you have to watch out for is that the threads don't use the same elements of each vector or you will have to add mutexes to synchronize access.

Splitting the vector in half using `v.begin()',` v.end()`and`std::midpoint` is the best way to go if the work per element is roughly constant.

So run your threads with:

```
{
    v_vector.resize(vector.size());
    auto mid = std::midpoint(vector.begin(), vector.end());
    auto v_mid = std::midpoint(v_vector.begin(), v_vector.end());
    std::jthread thread1(compute, vector.begin(), mid, v_vector.begin());
    std::jthread thread2(compute, mid, vector.end(), v_mid);
}
```

Comment: Hi Goswin, each thread will be technically resizing the vector after each math operation result is pushed into it, so **vector** 2.1million lines of text, **v_vector** (currently empty). threads read from **vector**, compute, push computed results into **v_vector**. **v_vector** now contains 2.1million indices of the computed results.

Comment: If you aren’t pre sizing your output vector, you’re gonna be in for a slow day pushing back 2mil entries.

Comment: @Mutlithrd Is there any reason you want to push values into the vector? Not only the results may be indeterministic (because you don't know the order of execution of threads), but also it may significant slow down to reallocate `v_vector`. The general approach would be to first `resize()` `v_vector` first and then access it with indices.